# Why can't the Mail block see my variable?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm new to Ruby and wondering why I am getting an error in this situation using the 'mail' gem in a simple Sinatra app:

```
post "/email/send" do

  @recipient = params[:email]

  Mail.deliver do 
    to @recipient # throws error as this is undefined
    from 'server@domain.com'
    subject 'testing sendmail'
    body 'testing sendmail'
  end

  erb :email_sent

end
```

This however works fine:

```
post "/email/send" do

  Mail.deliver do 
    to 'me@domain.com'
    from 'server@domain.com'
    subject 'testing sendmail'
    body 'testing sendmail'
  end

  erb :email_sent

end
```

I suspect this is something to do with block scope and my misunderstanding of it.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is with the instance var, and not with `params[:email]`? Have you tried outputting it? Also a local variable should be enough here, since the block is a closure anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Julik says, `Mail#delivery` executes your block using `#instance_exec`, which simply changes `self` while running a block (you wouldn't be able to call methods `#to` and `#from` inside the block otherwise).

What you really can do here is to use a fact that blocks are **closures**. Which means that it "remembers" all the local variables around it.

```
recipient = params[:email]
Mail.deliver do 
    to recipient # 'recipient' is a local variable, not a method, not an instance variable
...
end
```

Again, briefly:

- instance variables and method calls depend on `self`
- `#instance_exec` changes the `self`;
- local variables don't depend on `self` and are remembered by blocks because blocks are **closures**.

Comment: And a little addition: this behavior does not depend on a version of Ruby. So I'd remove words "Ruby 1.9" from the question title, it may be confusing.

Comment: So my mistake was using an instance variable? I used an instance variable because I wanted that data available in the ERB template and - if I am not mistaken - that means it needs to be an instance var. I can work around that, either by declaring a local variable, or using one of the approaches The Tin Man suggests. Thanks, loving Ruby so far, but lots to learn :)

Answer (score 10):

If you'll read through the docs for [`Mail`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/2.3.0/frames) further you'll find a nice alternate solution that will work. Rather than use:

```
Mail.deliver do 
  to @recipient # throws error as this is undefined
  from 'server@domain.com'
  subject 'testing sendmail'
  body 'testing sendmail'
end
```

you can use Mail's `new()` method, passing in parameters, and ignore the block:

```
Mail.new(
  to:      @recipient,
  from:    'server@domain.com',
  subject: 'testing sendmail',
  body:    'testing sendmail'
).deliver!
```

or the alternate hash element definitions:

```
Mail.new(
  :to      => @recipient,
  :from    => 'server@domain.com',
  :subject => 'testing sendmail',
  :body    => 'testing sendmail'
).deliver!
```

In pry, or irb you'd see:

```
pry(main)> Mail.new(
pry(main)* to: 'me@domain.com',
pry(main)* from: 'me@' << `hostname`.strip,
pry(main)* subject: 'test mail gem',
pry(main)* body: 'this is only a test'
pry(main)* ).deliver!
=> #<Mail::Message:59273220, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 09:01:14 -0700>, <From: me@myhost.domain.com>, <To: me@domain.com>, <Message-ID: <4eaad1cab65ce_579b2e8e6c42976d@myhost.domain.com>>, <Subject: test mail gem>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>
```

The [`new`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mail/2.3.0/Mail#new-class_method) method has several variations you can use. This is from the docs also, and might work better:

> As a side note, you can also create a new email through creating a Mail::Message object directly and then passing in values via string, symbol or direct method calls. See Mail::Message for more information.

```
 mail = Mail.new
 mail.to = 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
 mail[:from] = 'bob@test.lindsaar.net'
 mail['subject'] = 'This is an email'
 mail.body = 'This is the body'
```

followed by `mail.deliver!`.

Also note, in the previous example, that there are multiple ways to access the various headers in the message envelope. It's a flexible gem that seems to be well thought out and nicely follows the Ruby way.

Comment: Thanks for doing that research for me :) I'd had been looking too closely at the GitHub docs, instead of going to look at the RubyGems ones. Lesson learned there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because the Mail gem uses `instance_exec` under the hood. `instance_exec` uses instance variables from the object it's being called on and not from the caller. What I'd do is find a method in the Mail gem that does not use instance tricks but passes an explicit configuration object to the block, and proceed from there. Spares a few gray hairs.