# Ruby_send the result of scraping through email

Tags: ruby, email, web-scraping, nokogiri

With Ruby, my app:

- checks if the page status is 200
- Parses the PDF files if so
- sends via email the result of scraping

Having tested all the parts of the code, everything works fine, except one thing, the mail that is sent doesn't contain the result of my scrpaing;

What is the issue, is it related to the variable @monscrape that may be not recongnised in the final party of the code ?

My code:

```
require 'open-uri'
require "net/http"
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf/reader'
require 'mail'


options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port                 => 587,
        :domain               => 'gmail.com',
        :user_name            => 'mail@gmail.com',
        :password             => 'pwd',
        :authentication       => 'plain',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true  
 }

lien= "http://www.example.com"
url = URI.parse(lien)
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
res = req.request_head(url.path)
if res.code == "200"
    io     = open('http://www.example.com')
    reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
    reader.pages.each do |page|
    res = page.text
    @monscrape =  res.scan(/text[\s\S]*text/)
end

Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, options
end

Mail.deliver do
    to 'mail@hotmail.com'
    from 'Author <mail@gmail.com>'
    subject 'testing sendmail'
    html_part do
        content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        body '<h1>Please find below the scrape <%= @monscrape %></h1>'  
    end
end

else

    puts "the link doenst work"

end
```

Comment: Have you also tested that `@monscrape` actually contains something and is not `nil`?

Comment: yes, already confirmed that @monscrape contains the exprected result. thank you

Comment: What if you do `@monscrape = "test"`, and then run your program. Does the e-mail contain the word `"test"` then?

Comment: Just tried, the email is blank (the word "test" does not appear).
Any idea ? many thanks

Comment: In which line have you tested that @monoscrape contains the expected results?

Comment: What about: body "<h1>Please find below the scrape #{@monscrape}</h1>"

Comment: Why do you use Net::HTTP *and* OpenURI? They're going to retrieve the exact same information.

Comment: @theTinMan, he's using request_head

Comment: Then he should continue to use Net::HTTP to retrieve the rest of the information. Switching horses mid-stream is only confusing and results in code bloat. Or, better yet, use something like RestClient which provides all the features of Net::HTTP and OpenURI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `Mail.deliver` block is evaluated using [`instance_eval`](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/641da656ce603fed7cd68f46865371ecff99e7dc/lib/mail/message.rb#L132). Therefore no local instance `@variables` will be visible to the `Mail` block.

So `@monscrape` will always be `nil` inside the `Mail.deliver` block.

One solution is to use a local (non-instance) variable instead:

```
monscrape = "test"

Mail.deliver do
  ...
     body "<h1>Please find below the scrape #{monscrape}</h1>"
  ...
end
```

Also note that `Mail` does not support ERB(!) therefore you cannot use something like `<%= monscrape %>` in the body. You have to treat it like a normal string using string expansion with double quotes `"` and not single quotes `'`.

See further discussion and options here:
[Why can't the Mail block see my variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928844/why-cant-the-block-see-my-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
res = req.request_head(url.path)
```

when `url.path` returns `""`. `request_head` expects a path of at least `"/"`. That implies you need to fix up the URL being passed so it at least has the root path "/".

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com')
url.path # => ""
req.request_head(url.path)
*** ArgumentError Exception: HTTP request path is empty
```

vs.

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/')
url.path # => "/"
req.request_head(url.path)
#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

The second problem is you're trying to read something as PDF that *isn't* a PDF file. Example.com returns HTML, which is text. You can't use:

```
io     = open('http://www.example.com')
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
```

Trying to returns "PDF does not contain EOF marker".

It's really important that you understand what types of objects/resources are being returned by a site when you request a URL. You can't declare them willy-nilly and expect code to accept it without errors.

Comment: How does this fix the problem he has? He said he sees the expected value inside @monoscrape

Comment: The problem is his code can't even get to the point of retrieving valid resources. Without that the question is moot as we have to have valid code to work with, based on valid assumptions. Try running the code as is and see if you can even get to that point.

Comment: he said he confirmed that @monoscrape contains the desired output